# Combine hover and click selections in Altair

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I want to combine hover and click in selections in Altair plot. The code below produces the result that I want: points are mostly transparent by default, hovering over the point increases the opacity, and then clicking on the point increases the opacity even more. I find this useful so that users can hover over a point to get a quick sense of the results, and then click on the point to "lock" the selection. While I am satisfied with the results, the method seems a bit cumbersome because I need to define different chart layers for the hover and click selections. If I could construct a multi-way condition expression, then it seems like I would be able to simplify the code quite a bit. I tried writing the opacity condition as `alt.condition(click_selection, CLICK_OPACITY, alt.condition(hover_selection, HOVER_OPACITY, DEFAULT_OPACITY))`, but I got an error. Is there a way to simplify my code below to combine hover and click selections?

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a_values = np.arange(1, 4)
x_values = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
DEFAULT_OPACITY = 0.3
HOVER_OPACITY = 0.5
CLICK_OPACITY = 1.0

a_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a_values})

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.tile(A=a_values, reps=len(x_values)),
    'x': np.repeat(a=x_values, repeats=len(a_values)),
})
df['y'] = df['a'] * np.sin(2 * np.pi * df['x'])

hover_selection = alt.selection_single(
    clear='mouseout',
    empty='none',
    fields=['a'],
    name='hover_selection',
    on='mouseover',
)
click_selection = alt.selection_single(
    empty='none',
    fields=['a'],
    name='click_selection',
    on='click',
)

a_base = alt.Chart(a_df).mark_point(
    filled=True, size=100,
).encode(
    x=alt.X(shorthand='a:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(min(a_values) - 1, max(a_values) + 1))),
    y=alt.Y(shorthand='a:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(min(a_values) - 1, max(a_values) + 1))),
)
a_hover = a_base.encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(hover_selection, alt.value(HOVER_OPACITY), alt.value(DEFAULT_OPACITY))
).add_selection(hover_selection)
a_click = a_base.encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(click_selection, alt.value(CLICK_OPACITY), alt.value(0.0)),
).add_selection(click_selection)

y_base = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X(shorthand='x:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 2))),
    y=alt.Y(shorthand='y:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(-3, 3))),
)
y_hover = y_base.encode(
    opacity=alt.value(HOVER_OPACITY),
).transform_filter(hover_selection)
y_click = y_base.encode(
    opacity=alt.value(CLICK_OPACITY),
).transform_filter(click_selection)

alt.hconcat(
    alt.layer(a_hover, a_click),
    alt.layer(y_hover, y_click),
)
```

Comment: You can use [interactions operators](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#composing-multiple-selections) to compose conditions that depend on logical combinations of multiple inputs, but I don't think there is a way to have them triggering different outputs. I'll see if I can come up with an example in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VegaLite supports multiple selections in the same condition, but I don't think it is possible to write within `alt.Condition`. However, you can see the `alt.Condition` returns a dictionary so you could write this directly passing a list of selections.

This way you could clarify this section

```
a_base = alt.Chart(a_df).mark_point(
    filled=True, size=100,
).encode(
    x=alt.X(shorthand='a:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(min(a_values) - 1, max(a_values) + 1))),
    y=alt.Y(shorthand='a:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(min(a_values) - 1, max(a_values) + 1))),
)
a_hover = a_base.encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(hover_selection, alt.value(HOVER_OPACITY), alt.value(DEFAULT_OPACITY))
).add_selection(hover_selection)
a_click = a_base.encode(
    opacity=alt.condition(click_selection, alt.value(CLICK_OPACITY), alt.value(0.0)),
).add_selection(click_selection)
```

to something like this:

```
hover_and_click_condition = {
    'condition': [
        {'selection': 'hover_selection', 'value': HOVER_OPACITY},
        {'selection': 'click_selection', 'value': CLICK_OPACITY}],
     'value': DEFAULT_OPACITY}

a = alt.Chart(a_df).mark_point(
    filled=True, size=100,
).encode(
    x=alt.X(shorthand='a:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(min(a_values) - 1, max(a_values) + 1))),
    y=alt.Y(shorthand='a:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(min(a_values) - 1, max(a_values) + 1))),
    opacity=hover_and_click_condition
).add_selection(hover_selection, click_selection)
```

---

For the transform filters, you could rewrite this section

```
y_base = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X(shorthand='x:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 2))),
    y=alt.Y(shorthand='y:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(-3, 3))),
)
y_hover = y_base.encode(
    opacity=alt.value(HOVER_OPACITY),
).transform_filter(hover_selection)
y_click = y_base.encode(
    opacity=alt.value(CLICK_OPACITY),
).transform_filter(click_selection)

alt.hconcat(
    alt.layer(a_hover, a_click),
    alt.layer(y_hover, y_click),
)
```

like this:

```
y = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X(shorthand='x:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, 2))),
    y=alt.Y(shorthand='y:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=(-3, 3))),
    opacity=hover_and_click_condition
)

a | (y.transform_filter(click_selection) + y.transform_filter(hover_selection))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! One issue that I'm having is that if I click-select a point on the left plot, and then hover over another point on the left plot, then the region between the two curves on the right plot is shaded. I am using JupyterLab 1.2.6 if that makes a difference (although I'm not sure how to check the Vega-lite version).

Comment: @Stirling Yes, that's what I meant with the caveat I mentioned: "But if you are OK with a slight difference (the delta between the lines highlighted when having one point selected and hovering over another one),...". I didn't find another way to simplify the second part, only the first section.

Comment: @Stirling Actually I just thought of a solution. It is slightly more verbose compared to what I first wrote, but the result is exactly the same as in your question, I edited my answer.