# How to implement a conditional with more than 2 options?

Tags: altair

I would like to be able to nest `alt.condition` statements so I can have more than 2 possible values, but haven't been able to find relevant examples or work out the syntax on my own

This is my current code

```
   tenor_text = alt.Chart(src).mark_text(align='right',
                                          fontWeight='bold',
                                          fillOpacity=1,
                                          angle=45,
                                          fill='white',
                                          clip=False,
                                          dx=-5,
                                          dy=-5).encode(x=accrual_col_,
                                                        y=val_col_,
                                                        text=alt.condition(time_selection,
                                                                           val_col_,
                                                                           alt.value(' ')),
                                                        opacity=alt.condition(tenor_highlight | tenor_selection,
                                                                              alt.value(1),
                                                                              alt.value(0.5)),
                                                        fill=alt.condition(tenor_selection,
                                                                           alt.Color(tenor_col_,
                                                                                     sort=tenor_sorted.tenor.values),
                                                                           alt.value('lightgray'))
                                                        )
```

what I would *like* to able to do is something along the lines of

```
alt.condition(tenor_highlight, alt.condition( tenor_selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.5)), alt.value(0.1) ))
```

combine selectors and produce a richer set of possible values, but I haven't been able to work out the syntax so far.  Any suggestions appreciated (and to the devs, this is fantastic library!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine hover and click selections in Altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108224/combine-hover-and-click-selections-in-altair). Also https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2759